# Update BIOS on Dell XPS

Tags: bios

I would like to upgrade the BIOS.

I found here the last upgrade: https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=w5c0w&oscode=wb64a&productcode=xps-13-9343-laptop&lwp=rt

It is the number 20 and I believe I have the number 9 installed.

Should I apply all available updates or only the last one is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you only need the latest update unless otherwise stated. Go with number 20.

Before the update:

- Disconnect all external devices like USB drives, docking station etc.
- Make sure your battery is charged and an AC adapter is connected
- Read and follow the installation instructions

Good luck!